# Put each statement in if-clause on new line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

In Eclipse formatter for Java how can I format if-statements like

```
if (x != null
    && x.getSomething() != null
    && x.getSomething().getSomethingMore()) {
  y.doSomething();
}
```

if they exceed the max line width (each statement on new line!). I thought it should be done with

[image]

but somehow I am wrong. Result:

```
if (x != null && x.getSomething() != null
    && x.getSomething().getSomethingMore()) {
 y.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: The way I'm going is that I set a very different setting: don't un-break manual line-breaks. This way whenever I want some 'special' line break, Eclipse will preserve them for me. This has turned out to be much more dynamic and easier to handle than all the individual special settings.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't follow. Could you make an example or provide a screenshot or something.

Comment: I looked it up: It's under "Line Wrapping" and is called "Never join already wrapped lines". This way if you manually insert a line break, Eclipse will respect that, and you get formattings like you want easily.

Comment: Thanks, that seemes to work. But why is the option mentioned in the question not working? Isn't that exactly for that case?

Comment: There's probably some other setting colliding with the ones you set, I assume. Maybe some formatter-internal rule priority "problem". Try settings the second option to "wrap all elements, every element on a new line", that might work as intended. But you know, I've solved that problem with "Never join already wrapped lines" years ago, so I don't know much more details.

Comment: I'm not using the auto-wrapping functions at all, especially because I often got very simple checks like `if (done && isValid) ...;` that I wanna keep on the same line. And formatters never get it formatted the way I want in all cases. So in the end I waste 80% less time if I simply wrap the lines myself and force Eclipse not to join them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. You are right, I end up wasting time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to select the following options:

```
- Wrap all elements, every element on a new line
```

I do:

```
- Wrap before operators
- Wrap all elements, every element on a new line
- Force split
- Indent by one
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I hope this help you.